# set result and check rowcount in one if

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

why does this not work?

```
if($result = $db->execute($params) && $result->rowCount() > 0)
```

I get an error when the $db->execute fails that $result is a non-object.

of course it is. $result equals FALSE so it should skip the rowCount check shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if($result = $db->execute($params) && $result->rowCount() > 0)
```

is the same as

```
if($result = ($db->execute($params) && $result->rowCount() > 0))
```

You should do

```
if(($result = $db->execute($params)) && ($result->rowCount() > 0))
```

Or, even better:

```
$result = $db->execute($params);
if($result && $result->rowCount() > 0)
```